# Calling a .jar file multiple times from another application

Tags: java, r, clojure, jvm

I have some code that I wrote in clojure and compiled it into a .jar file which is called repeatedly by a collaborator working in R. The problem is that this executable is called repeatedly in the R application and the JVM needs to be spun up every single time. The total runtime of my code is negligible yet starting up the JVM every single time is considerable.

Is there a more elegant way to get applications that run on the JVM to interact with other applications?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider change your application to a EJB or a WebService if is possible.

If is not possible, you can try manager requests in a queue in your application and process in different threads.